# Is that the Debian stretch/sid is an unstable version?

Tags: debian

The `/etc/os-release` file contains the following:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux stretch/sid"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

I don't clear if the `streth/sid` means unstable version. By Debian's doc, `sid` means `unstable`, but `stretch` means `testing`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`stretch/sid` in `/etc/os-release` means either testing, or unstable, or a mixture of both, during the Stretch development cycle.

`/etc/os-release` is provided by `base-files`; we don't attempt to keep a testing-specific version, different from an unstable-specific version, so the version in testing and unstable just has the current testing codename and "sid". When testing is frozen before the release, `base-files` is updated with the release name.

Comment: So, it means there is no distinct difference between unstable and testing before freeze？

Comment: There is, but packages migrate from unstable to testing all the time (before the freeze), so trying to maintain a distinction in a package is rather pointless. Anything uploaded to unstable is supposed to target testing eventually. The [wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting) has more details.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. By the way, where could I report when I encounter bugs or broken packages.

Comment: The best way to report bugs in Debian is to use the `reportbug` tool (run `reportbug` in a terminal window).